# Values not going to controller method using Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using `MVC 4` and want to send a form and some other values to `controller` method using `Ajax Call` but i am unable to do that after trying so hard.Please look at my code below and guide me with some enhancements in my code.

Code of my script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

           var ids = [];
        $("#btnproceed").click(function () {
            debugger;
            //   $("div[class^='apple-']")

            $("div[class^='dvDynamic_']").each(function () {
                debugger;


                var pids = $(this).text();

                ids.push(pids);

            });

            ids = [];
 });
```

Code of form to serialize and send:

```
          <form id="customerform">
            <div id="customerdetails">
                <label>Your Information</label><br />

                @*@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count; i++) {*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders.Customer, new { @placeholder = "Enter Your Full Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Orders.Customer)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders.Phone, new { @placeholder = "Enter Your Cell Number" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Orders.Phone)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Orders.Address, new { @rows = 3, @cols = 2, @style = "width:300px;", @placeholder = "Enter Your  Complete Delivery Address" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Orders.Address)


                <input id="btnback" type="button" value="Back" /> <input id="btnsubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />  @*<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />*@

            </div>
        </form>
```

Code of my final submit button:

```
       $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {

         debugger;


            var form = [{ "name": "customerinfo", "value": JSON.stringify($('#customerform')) }];
            var data = JSON.stringify({
                'products': ids,
                'customerinfo': form

            });

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetIds", "Store")",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }
        });
});
```

and code of my receiving method in `controller`

```
 public JsonResult GetIds(string products, string customerinfo)
 {
 }
```

values in controller method are coming empty

Comment: please help to overcome this issue

Comment: Why do you declare an array `ids = [];`, populate it in an `$.each()` and reset it back to an empty array (the last line of the first script)? What are you really wanting to post? The form and an additional array of values?

Comment: @StephenMuecke  yes, i want to post a form and values in an array ids that will come from a previous button click..is the method to get values of ids [] correct ?

Comment: Your first script resets it back to an empty array. You should be posting back you model, not a string. What is your model declared in the view i.e. `@model ???`

Comment: @StephenMuecke  model ProductOrderViewModel

Comment: Post the request you are sending to the server. You can find it using Fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize your form and append additional data to it

```
var data = $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'products': ids }, true);
var url = '@Url.Action("GetIds", "Store")';
$.post(url, data, function(r) { alert r.Id; });
```

and change you method to

```
public JsonResult GetIds(ProductOrderViewModel  model, string[] products)
```

However you first script initializes a new array (`var ids = [];`), adds objects to it and then resets it to an empty array (the last line of your code is `ids = [];`). Suggest you just test this by using `var ids = []; ids.push('abc'); ids.push('def');` to test initially.

Comment: dear values coming this way but how to modify to get values from first button click's script of ids[]

Comment: yes it is binding correctly..but i want to get ids[] values where i am filling the array from first button click.how can i do that

Comment: As for the `ids` - just remove the last line of code - `ids = [];`. But your code suggests a problem with your design anyway - your just getting the `.text()` of elements which are not editable so it means your just sending back data which you already know in the controller.

Comment: actually i am getting the whole string and aiming to split that at backend to get id from that strings....by removing last line ids = []; .each function will not work and only the last value pushed in array will be in ids

Comment: Yes it will work. Did you try `var ids = []; ids.push('abc'); ids.push('def');` - in the POST method, products will be `["abc", "def"]`. You need to debug the script and check what the value of `Ids` actually is just before you call the `$.post()` method. I'm not sure what your `$.each()` is actually doing and how it relates to your html so a bit hard to help with that one. You would need to ask a new question with a bot more detail :)

Comment: values with hard coded push methods are coming but i want to get ids values from first script..can you help to improve it ?

Comment: You will need to ask a new question showing the scripts and html associated with that script (for example it refers to `$("div[class^='dvDynamic_']")` - what are those elements?)

Comment: please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178021/how-to-get-values-from-a-button-click-event-to-another-button-click-event

Comment: Just seen the question. And the excepted answer is exactly what I stated in my comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a more complex model to bind the form data. Something like this:

```
public JsonResult GetIds(InputModel model)
{

}

public class InputModel
{
    public string[] Products { get; set; }
    public CustomerInfoModel CustomerInfo { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerInfoModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

You could do some refactoring and skip the `JSON.stringify($('#customerform'))` part and instead match the model with your form.

Comment: dear you mean every thing else is Ok ?

Comment: I assume the ajax post you send to the endpoint is correct. Otherwise you need to post the json request here.

Comment: please suggest some other solution as its not working