# How to get values from a button click event to another button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get values from a div on button click event and get those values in another button click event.But not able to fetch those values in other click's event.
here is code of my div:

```
'<div class="dvDynamic_' + pid + '"><span class="count_' + pid + '">' + count + '</span><span id="pname" style = "margin-left:70px;">' + pname + '</span><span id="punitprice" style = "margin-left:150px;">' + uprice + '</span></div>'
```

Code of First Button click event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ids = [];
    $("#btnproceed").click(function () {
        debugger;
        //   $("div[class^='apple-']")
        $("div[class^='dvDynamic_']").each(function () {
            debugger;
            var pids = $(this).text();
            ids.push(pids);
        });
        ids = [];
    });
```

Code of Second button click :

```
$('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
    debugger;
    var form = [{
        "name": "customerinfo",
        "value": JSON.stringify($('#customerform'))
    }];
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        'products': ids,
        'customerinfo': form
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("
        GetIds ", "
        Store ")",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Name the function in the second button and call it by name instead of as an anonymous function

Comment: @Deepak can u give a code idea ?

Comment: you clear `ids` array in first function `ids = [];` directly after loop and fill it with data, so after execute `$("#btnproceed").click` you always have `ids = [];`

Comment: @Grundy what you want to suggest ?

Comment: don't do that :-) or clear it before loop by elements

Comment: @Grundy is right- Remove this Line ids = []; from the first click event and place it before the loop executes

Comment: @Grundy do not understand what you want to say

Comment: @user3772251, try see my answer, possibly it more clear than comment :-)

Comment: @DawoodAwan can you tell me how to get id from the dive given in my question ..id is concatinated with div's class '<div class="dvDynamic_' + pid + '">

Comment: Why do you want to get the ids from the class? Add them as data attributes... e.g. data-product-id="3" data-item-id="4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now you clear array `ids` on each execute `$("#btnproceed").click` handler

```
$("#btnproceed").click(function () {
    debugger;
    //   $("div[class^='apple-']")
    $("div[class^='dvDynamic_']").each(function () {
        debugger;
        var pids = $(this).text();
        ids.push(pids);
    });
    ids = []; // here you clear all ids added in previous each loop
});
```

just remove this line `ids = [];` or move this to method start

```
$("#btnproceed").click(function () {
    ids = []; // here you clear all ids added in previous handler
    debugger;
    //   $("div[class^='apple-']")
    $("div[class^='dvDynamic_']").each(function () {
        debugger;
        var pids = $(this).text();
        ids.push(pids);
    });
    //before method exit - ids array contain data added in previous loop
});
```

Comment: can you tell me how to get id from the dive given in my question ..id is concatinated with div's class '<div class="dvDynamic_' + pid + '">

Comment: @user3772251, i not quite understand what exactly you expect? can you provide simple sample output? in html i not see that you use id

Comment: suppose i got string through .text(); i want to get the value separated from each element...like i got "41sugar100" but i want to get as "4 1 sugar 100"...is there any way in Jquery to get text like that ?NOTE i don't want to split manually

Comment: @user3772251, you cann't do this with one `text` as i understand you just need get text from each nested span, something like `$(this).find('id_or_class_nested_span').text()`, also if you fill this with loop, you have a problem with same id like `span id="punitprice"` in this case better used `class`

Comment: @user3772251, already provide it: `$(this).find('id_or_class_nested_span').text()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87765/discussion-between-grundy-and-user3772251).

Comment: @user3772251, Your getting the `.text()` of the `<div>` element which returnd the inner text of all the elements in it so if `count=41` and `pname=:sugar"` and `uprice=100` then you will get `41sugar100`. The real issue here is that your html structure is wrong and its hard to understand exactly why you are doing this and for what purpose are your are posting this back as I noted in your previous question